# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler" asking me for the incompatible versions of the bundler i have and the bundler required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to install the bundle in my rails app and getting the same error this whole time ..

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (= 1.0.18) ruby

Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.7.4)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

I have tried almost each suggestions that've been suggested but none so far worked for me.
Can anybody help..??
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Bundler does not need to be on Gemfile.

You can remove the line that contains `bundler` in Gemfile, then run `bundle` again.

The reason this is failing is because your system has probably a newer version of bundler than the Gemfile is asking for.

Comment: I removed the bundler statement from the Gemfile and now am getting this error which I found over here but none of the solution worked for me..
This is the following error:

`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.7.4)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.`

Need your help.. :/

Comment: that might be caused by a line containing bundler in Gemfile.lock, try removing it